# Pydot parser : reading custom attributes in a node

Tags: pydot

I have dot graph string like

I know I can use node.get_name() or node.get_label() to read name/label.

what methods in the library can I use to read the custom properties like 'schema' or 'page' in the above case?

Posted in pydot github page. No response

````
"Graph_ID_1" [label="My graph" schema="my_schema" page=2];
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_attributes` on nodes function will give you a dict with all the attributes.

```py
import pydot
n = pydot.Node(my_attr="bar")
print(n.get_attributes()) # -> {'my_attr': 'bar'}
```